# Android Medirecorder start failed on Android >=6

Tags: android

I'm trying to record outgoing and incoming calls in my app. I use approach from this [tutorial](http://www.benmccann.com/android-audio-recording-tutorial/). Mediarecorder start() method is called from BroadcastReceiver, when incoming or outgoing calls starts.

I use audiosource -  `recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);`
for recording voice from both sides.

I also set this parameters to default:

```
 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
```

This works fine on Android 5, but i get next Error on Android 8:

```
                                                                          Process: myseolife.ru.androidcrm:remote, PID: 6305
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x1000010 (has extras) } in myseolife.ru.androidcrm.broadcastreceivers.PhoneCallReceiver@f23996c
                                                                              at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$-android_app_LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args_51267(LoadedApk.java:1305)
                                                                              at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.$m$0(Unknown Source:4)
                                                                              at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.run(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
                                                                              at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
                                                                              at myseolife.ru.androidcrm.utils.AudioRecorder.start(AudioRecorder.java:58)
                                                                              at myseolife.ru.androidcrm.broadcastreceivers.PhoneCallReceiver.onOutgoingCallStarted(PhoneCallReceiver.java:82)
                                                                              at myseolife.ru.androidcrm.broadcastreceivers.CallReceiver.onCallStateChanged(CallReceiver.java:88)
                                                                              at myseolife.ru.androidcrm.broadcastreceivers.CallReceiver.onReceive(CallReceiver.java:45)
                                                                              at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$-android_app_LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args_51267(LoadedApk.java:1295)
                                                                              at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.$m$0(Unknown Source:4) 
                                                                              at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.run(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

I thought, it was permissions issue, but i think i have all needed permissions (here is all permissions from my manifest):

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" />
```

And Permissions list for Runtime request:

```
  String[] permissions= new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,};
```

Now i don't know, where to find the solution for this problem. What can be wrong here?

**UPDATE:** If change `recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);`
to
`recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);`
The error disappears, but MIC can record only my voice..

Comment: are you sure you got runtime permission?

Comment: @HariharanSaravanan i made screenshots of all asked permissions - goo.gl/iTNajf

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
recorder.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

instead of

```
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Try this ,it might work for u.

setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
 setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS)
 setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in:
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL)

It doesn't work on some devices because call recording is not allowed in some countries. So I choose to use MIC and turn ON the speaker at the max volume to record call from speaker into the mic. My piece of code:

```
     try {
                    while(true) {
                        sleep(2000);
                        if (!audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn())
                            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                        int sb2value = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(audioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
                        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,sb2value,0);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```